# Not Getting anything back after calling Fetch API - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a React Native in which i am sending my Form's data to Backend Node.js using Fetch and that worked all fine but i cannot execute anything down after fetch api, even console.log is not running.

**React-Native Code:**

```
const PostData  = () =>{

        console.log("Posting");


        //Sending Request to Node.js using Fetch API
        fetch("http://192.168.0.107:3000/Adminsignup", {

            //Setting Method
            method:"POST",

            //Setting Headers
            headers:{
                //Setting Content-Type
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            //Stringifying the email and password and storing it into body
            body:JSON.stringify({
                name,
                gmail,
                password,
                retype
            })
        }).then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

`.then` and `.catch` of fetch api is not working.

Comment: why you are mixing async-await and promise? . either use async await or promise

Comment: ok i am using async now but still i am getting no response back

Comment: If you have really switched to the async style completely, and aren't using `then()`anymore, then please edit your post to show the new code.

Comment: i tried to go with promise, now my code is updated

Comment: In the code you shared, you have defined a function, but you are not calling it. Are you actually calling `PostData()` anywhere?

Comment: yes i am caling PostData and its working because i can see result of console.log("Posting");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your front-end code is all good and as u said that your backend is also working when you fire PostData() function, check if you are returning the response from backend.

Add this in your signup Route:

```
res.status(200).send({result:"Successfully got Response"})
```

Catch status in your front-end like this:

```
let final = await fetch("http://192.168.0.107:5000/studentSignup", {
            //Setting Method
            method:"POST",
            //Setting Headers
            headers:{

                //Setting Content-Type
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            //Stringifying the email and password and storing it into body
            body:JSON.stringify({name,gmail,password,retype})
        })

        const data = final.status;
        if(data === 200)
        {
            navigation.navigate("Your Route");
        }
```